# Yii Kartik DateControl Time Formatter Only Displays 12:30 On Update

Tags: yii, yii2

I am using the Yii Kartik DateControl Widget to allow for the time selection to be displayed in one PHP format but saved in another. The primary issue I am having is that when I save save the time selection and go back (to edit the model) it will always display 12:30pm.

For instance, I select "6:30pm" from the time picker.
It correctly saves in the database "18:30:00". 
On update the display should read: "6:30pm", but instead shows "12:30pm". 
Whatever the saved time is, it always switches to "12:30pm" on update. And I know it switches because the widget time button is highlighted in green.

The following is my module setup:

```
'modules' => [
    'datecontrol' =>  [
        'class' => 'kartik\datecontrol\Module',
        'displaySettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'HH:mm a',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm a', 
        ],
        'saveSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => 'php:Y-m-d', // saves as unix timestamp
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => 'php:H:i:s',
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => 'php:Y-m-d H:i:s',
        ],
        'displayTimezone' => 'America/New_York',
        'saveTimezone' => 'America/New_York',
        'autoWidget' => true,
        'ajaxConversion' => true,
        'autoWidgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => ['type'=>2, 'pluginOptions'=>['autoclose'=>true]], // example
            Module::FORMAT_DATETIME => [], // setup if needed
            Module::FORMAT_TIME => [], // setup if needed
        ],
```

This is the setup in my view:

```
<?= $form->field($event, 'start_time')->label(false)->widget(DateControl::classname(), [
                'type' => DateControl::FORMAT_TIME,
        ]); ?>
```

I either did something wrong here or there is a bug in the widget but I haven't figured it out. 
Things I've tried:

1. Changing the saveTimezone to 'UTC'
2. Setting the timezones in the widget itself at the view level
3. Setting AjaxConversion to false
4. Setting autoWidget to false

None of these really get me the desired effect as expected.

Comment: 'autoWidgetSettings' => [
            Module::FORMAT_DATE => ['type'=>2, 'pluginOptions'=>['autoclose'=>true]], // example
seems doubtful to me, although it's in documentation. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: I tried removing that.  It did not have any effect on either the day picker or the time picker.